# other users can't change or remove formatting in excel spreadsheets created using xlsxwriter

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

After successfully creating workbooks/sheets with the users requested formatting, highlighting etc. the user is unable to remove the formatting/highlighting, not even when they copy/paste values into another active workbook or a blank new workbook?

We tried to define formats to set 'locked' to 'false', as well as set all columns to 'unlock' as the very last command in the code.

## Define formats

```
red = inInvestigationWorkbook.add_format(conditional)
yellow = inInvestigationWorkbook.add_format(highlight)
unlocked = inInvestigationWorkbook.add_format({'locked': False})
```

## Format the worksheet to unlock all cells.

```
inInvestigationWorksheet.set_column('A:XDF', None, unlocked)
```

The users need to be able to copy the results to another workbook that keeps running monthly data, but when pasted the formatting comes with it, even if they use the copy/paste special/values. Un-formatting the cells does not work either... all cells remain color formatted.